# how to find a implicit val or def used at in idea IDE?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit

`Ctrl + Q` to find implicit conversion

`Shift + Cmd + P` to find the place of an implicit parameter instance

How do I find where an implicit value/def is used?

Comment: I think that "Show usage" list the implicit usage too, isn't it ?

Comment: "Show usage" does not list implicit usages, at least in my quick tests

Answer (score 3):

IntelliJ 2019.1 Scala Plugin now supports [finding usages of implicits](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/#find-usages), in particular, going from the definition to the usage via `Edit | Find | Find Usages`:

> ...previously the [implicits hints](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2018/08/17/how-to-use-the-new-features-of-intellij-scala-plugin-2018-2/) allowed you to see usages of
>   implicits and go from usages to definitions, but you couldn’t do the
>   reverse – go from definitions to usages, by invoking `Find Usages`.
>   Well, now you can...

The feature worked on my machine using both the IntelliJ's internal build tool, as well as system sbt version 1.2.7 via `Use sbt shell`.

Comment: This seems to be broken for BSP projects. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-18816.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the standard "Show usage" command ought to list where implicit values are used. It does not currently do so (IDEA v 2018.1), but I think that is just a bug (or omission).

I have raised https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-199104 to alert JetBrains to this bug; I suggest you vote for that and subscribe to changes there.

I can't see any workaround or any other way to do this in IDEA.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least a how key like Ctrl + Shift + Q to find implicits in scope